# How to search for 2 Words in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Example: "I have to really find this person".

Using the "find" feature, how do I search in a document for anything that will result in "to (anything)ly"?

The results will come back as:

**to** real**ly**

**to** truthful**ly**

**to** faithful**ly**

and so on.

I tried this: to(.*)ly>, but it's not exactly what I want. Also, it should be able to return results with possible extra spaces in between.

Comment: `\bto \w+ly\b` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
to \w*ly
```

This will match "to ly" too. If you do not want that, then replace the `*` with a `+`.